# Sub-tensor of a tensor with arbitrary degree in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, tensor

I have a function where I input a tensor `T` of arbitrary degree `d` which is of size `n1 x n2 x ... x nd`. I want to output the tensor `T(1:r,1:r,...,1:r)`. In other words, an `r x r x ... x r` sub-tensor with `d` number of `r`'s. I'm having difficulty working around the variable number `1:r`'s. Ideally I'd like to do this without reshaping `T` if possible.

Comment: can you show an example with d=5? I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: If d=5 is fixed, and say T is a 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 tensor and r = 3, then T(1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3) would be my desired output. My issue is that I want my input tensor T to have arbitrary degree d, so the number of times 1:3 is written depends on the d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite straightforward to do with cell arrays, consider following example:

```
% example setup
a = ones(3,3,3,3);
r = 2;
% create indices in cell array
b = cell(1,ndims(a));
b(:) = {1:r};
% evaluate
c = a(b{:});
disp(size(c))
```